# Clojure core.logic. Can I use complex data-structures in facts and rules?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to get to grips with core.logic.

Can I use complex data-structures in facts and rules?

For example, I'm trying to do this :

```
(pldb/db-rel test a)

(defn is-wibble? [a] (= true (:wibble a)))

(def facts
  (pldb/db
   [test {:name "x" :wibble true}]
   [test {:name "y" :wibble false}]
   [test {:name "z" :wibble true}]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (doseq [x
          (pldb/with-db facts
            (run* [q]
              (is-wibble? q)))]
    (println x))))
```

But it's throwing an error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
    at clojure.core.logic.Substitutions.bind(logic.clj:425)
    at polvo.core$_main$fn__377$fn__378$fn__379$_inc__380.invoke(core.clj:223)
```

Actually at the line

```
(is-wibble? q)
```

Am I wrong to try to create rules as normal functions? Or put complex data into facts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can examine complex data structures in your `db`, the only missing piece here is that in your `is-wibble?` predicate you'll be receiving a *logic variable* instead of an actual, concrete value.

There's a `pred` goal in core.logic that will `project` an lvar so you can examine its value. I renamed the goal to match typical goal names. `pred` takes an lvar and some function that will receive the lvar's value, and the `pred` goal succeeds if that predicate function returns truth-y.

```
(defn wibbleo [a] (pred a :wibble))
```

Or you could define it like this using your original predicate:

```
(defn wibbleo [a] (pred a is-wibble?))
```

Note you also need to include your `db-rel` as a goal `(test q)`, then your program should work:

```
(pldb/with-db facts
  (run* [q]
    (test q)
    (wibbleo q)))
=> ({:name "x", :wibble true} {:name "z", :wibble true})
```